# How can I know whether my subprocess is waiting for my input ?(in python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

file sp.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
s = input('Waiting for your input:')
print('Data:' + s)
```

file main.py

```
import subprocess as sp
pobj = sp.Popen('sp.py',stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,shell=True)
print(pobj.stdout.read().decode())
pobj.stdin.write(b'something...')
print(pobj.stdout.read().decode())
```

main.py will block in the first `pobj.stdout.read()`, because sp.py is waiting for me.
But if I want to process the string 'Waiting for you input:' first, how can I know whether sp.py is waiting for me ?
In other words, I want the `pobj.stdout.read()` to return when sp.py is waiting (or sleeping because of `time.sleep()`).

Comment: Have you tried to use `pobj.communicate`, as advised in the [subprocess doc](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: @PierreGM Thanks a lot. `communicate`will terminate the subprocess after being called.

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks a lot. It's helpful, but how can I distinguish between "still working" and "waiting for input" ?

Comment: Note that a process accepts input even if it isn't waiting for it, so you could write to pobj.stdin first, and it will get that input whenever it tries to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've worked it out. My code is based on [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) (Thanks, @VaughnCato)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess as sp
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue,Empty
import time

def getabit(o,q):
    for c in iter(lambda:o.read(1),b''):
        q.put(c)
    o.close()

def getdata(q):
    r = b''
    while True:
        try:
            c = q.get(False)
        except Empty:
            break
        else:
            r += c
    return r

pobj = sp.Popen('sp.py',stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,shell=True)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=getabit,args=(pobj.stdout,q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    print('Sleep for 1 second...')
    time.sleep(1)#to ensure that the data will be processed completely
    print('Data received:' + getdata(q).decode())
    if not t.isAlive():
        break
    in_dat = input('Your data to input:')
    pobj.stdin.write(bytes(in_dat,'utf-8'))
    pobj.stdin.write(b'\n')
    pobj.stdin.flush()
```